# Access 2010: How to Pre-fill new record with information from previous record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know how to Pre-fill a field in a new record with a field from it's previous record. To be specific I will provide an example.

The first record is the year 2013 with a "Final Percentage" of 95%.
The second record would be the year 2014 and it will have a Field that says "Last Year's Final Percentage." How do I get this field to populate the 95% from the previous record?

Comment: I would say that they would look up whether the previous record has the same ID as the new record (IE: NYC, 2013, 95%) So I would like the new record to show (NYC, 2014, 95%) with the 95% being pulled from the previous entry in a different field of course.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in a module that will use the access DLookup  function. Dlookup will let you get a single value from a single field of a table given certain criteria (ie get me last years row, and get the final percentage field .)

When you start a new record in a form, call this function to get the value you need, passing it criteria from the current record.

I think you will need to use the AfterUpdate event of the control that contains the criteria (ie the current year) to update the last year's value control.  This controls event VBA will use the function you wrote.

Harvey

Harvey

Comment: Harvey, can you provide me with a sample of how to do this? I am not too familiar with coding VBA.

Comment: No sorry.  Do some googling and buy an excel programming vba book